# Setting style on combo box on activated signal causes issues

Tags: c++, qt

Currently I have a QComboBox who's color I want to change when the user makes a selection. To do this I have function called on the activated signal which calls `setStyleSheet`

```
void comboBoxActivated(int i){
   myComboBox -> setStyleSheet("border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;");
}
```

This however causes the combo box to be stuck open on my screen and the only way to get rid of it is close the application. Is there some issue with changing the style using this function? For reference I am running Ubuntu and QT 4.8

Comment: Does it work if you change the style sheet in some other function? If you don't set the style sheet at all, it doesn't get stuck open? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @metal for security reasons I cannot post a screenshot, setting the style in a function that is *not* run on user interaction works but changing the style from a function that relies on user input signal does not. And yes not setting the style, the box works fine

Comment: Can you repro the problem in a smaller app that you could post code and a screenshot for?

Comment: try canging `"border-color:red;"` to `"border: 2px solid red;"`. I cannot try it in QT 4.8, but changing this in a QT5 application made it work.

Comment: @apalomer thanks for the response, unfortunately it doesn't seem to resolve the issue

Comment: Which signal are you using?

Comment: @Gasteizko `void QComboBox::activated(int index)`

Comment: I made an example in windows and Qt4.8 and works perfect... I will put the code in an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason if I force the box to open and close the change will apply without issue

```
void comboBoxActivated(int i){
   myComboBox -> setStyleSheet("border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;");
   myComboBox -> showPopup(); 
   myComboBox -> hidePopup(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code in windows works perfect:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->comboBox->addItem("item1");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("item2");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("itme3");

    connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(activated(int)),
            this,         SLOT(comboBoxActivated(int)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::comboBoxActivated(int i){
    ui->comboBox -> setStyleSheet("border-width:2px; border-style:solid; border-color:red;");
}
```